# using raw $_POST variables inside php ajax procedure

Tags: php, mysql

I want to know is that code vulnerable to sql injection?

My dilemma is based on fact that `$_POST` variables are used directly, without passing them like `$something = $_POST['src']`.

```
$sql = "update posts set img = :aimg where id = :aid";

$st = $db->prepare($sql);

$st->execute(array(
    ":aimg" => $_POST['src'],
    ":aid" => $_POST['id']
));

echo $_POST['src'];
```

Comment: The code which you have presented is secured properly because of parameterization.

Comment: And what possible benefit would there be in moving the values through a scalar variable?

Comment: `$something = $_POST['src']` is the same as using a plain `$_POST['src']`

Comment: I get the feeling that you would benefit from actually reading a few articles so you understand what SQL Injection actually is

Comment: @RiggsFolly I think that `$something = $_POST['src'];` is an unfortunate relic from bad tutorials and people started writing code like that without knowing why.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus On this one I definitely have to agree. I think it was popularised by chip manufacturers so developers use megabytes of unnecessary memory in their apps

Comment: @RiggsFolly, believe me, there is not simple tutorial, simple example about sql injection. Each of them a large story... very hard to see the essence.

Comment: So read them twice and thrice if necessary

Comment: you can read about data sanitation here https://www.dreamhost.com/blog/php-security-user-validation-sanitization/

Comment: @RiggsFolly, no, I'm not a professional programmer and have not so much free time.

Comment: Then hire a professional to do this job this is a risk

Comment: @Geomorillo, your desires are very delicate, i.e. the way you express them. It's not the right way, believe me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should validate every input, in this case $_POST['src'] and $_POST['id']. 
For example, if $_POST['id'] must be a number, validate that, and so on. Keep in mind that client could be other thing instead of a browser. Of course parameterization is a good practice but you can't rely just on that. By the way, assign $something = $_POST['src']; makes no difference.

Comment: validate that `$_POST['id']` is an integer - is that what you mean? And what else could be a client, besides a browser?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meat. There are a lot of tools, for example soapUI and Jmeter. You could also perform posts with bash, php etc.

Answer (score 0):

Basically $post=$_POST['src'] && $_POST['src'] are same. There is not any kind of securtiy enhancement by assigning the value to a variable. Query seems ok and secure.Prepared statements and paramerized variable make the things secure.